# How to export kernel functions which written in assembly?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, gcc, assembly

I am working with a `PowerPC` processor and have to use `dcache` functions in my kernel module, like: `"clean_dcache_range()"`, implemented in `$KERNEL_SOURCE/arch/powerpc/kernel/misc_32.S` (`version 4.1.8`). this assembly file is compiled during kernel compilation and `misc_32.o` object file exists in kernel build directory.
However, i can't use this functions in my kernel module and the error `"implicit declaration of function"` appears when i compile the module using `gcc`.
Also, the `Module.symvers` file does not contain these functions.
Note that, the mentioned functions are declared as `_GLOBAL`.
So, what is the problem and how can i solve it?